# What is the best way to test React component exported in withRouter()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component exported like this.

```
export default withRouter(injectIntl(MyComponent));
```

I'm using `shallow` for testing but can't test states and functions. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Test if the component you have exported has access to `props.history`. The `history` field is added to the `props` of the object if it is either called by a `<Route>` tag or you use a `withRouter()` method to export it.

So within the JS file of this component, add a `console.log(props.history)` inside the component. If the value is non-null, the `withRouter()` export is working properly with your component.

Answer (score 0):

When testing shallow created components wrapped with a HOC, one has to use `dive()` to get at the non wrapped component.

```
const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<MyComponent />).dive();
```

If you were using mount, then somethink like this would suffice:

```
const wrapper = enzyme.mount<MyComponent />).childAt(0);
```

in your case, you look like you have two HOC's to you might have to call dive twice. (`dive().dive()`)